# How can I share some twig templates across all pages in Oro application?

Tags: twig, orocrm, orocommerce

I have some twig blocks and templates, that should be used all over the application. How can I achieve this in Oro app?
I know there is a way to include twig from another folder with next syntax:

```
layout:
    actions:
        -   '@setBlockTheme':
                themes: ['casual.html.twig', '@SomeTheme/layouts/sometheme/common.html.twig']
```

But a flaw in this approach is the fact that I should include this common.html.twig in every yml file I want to use it.

Can I somehow add this common.html.twig file to all pages without this explicit inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the layout update file to the `Resources/views/layouts/<theme-name>/page/` folder in a bundle to apply it on every page.

**UPDATED:**

To use a template in all the pages you have to register it with setBlockTheme action using the layout update in the above directory. For more details see [the Oro Documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/templates/#dev-doc-frontend-apply-block-theme).

Comment: I don't actually need layout update file, just twig template that I will be able to use with `block('template_name')` twig function in other twig templates

Comment: I extended the answer then.